# Liquibase Different Datatypes H2/Oracle

Tags: oracle, h2, liquibase

So I do have the following changeset in my dbchangelog:

```
<changeSet id="04_04_2018" author="codeit">
    <createTable tableName="BSP_TABELLE">
        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="datum" type="datetime"/>
        <column name="richtigfalsch" type="boolean"/>
        <column name="blub" type="blob"/>
        <column name="club" type="clob"/>
        <column name="ganzzahl" type="int"/>
        <column name="grosseganzzahl" type="bigint"/>
        <column name="gleitkommazahl" type="decimal(17,5)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

In H2 I do get what I expected like:

```
CREATE TABLE BSP_TABELLE
(
  NAME           VARCHAR(255),
  DATUM          TIMESTAMP,
  RICHTIGFALSCH  BOOLEAN,
  BLUB           BLOB,
  CLUB           CLOB,
  GANZZAHL       INTEGER,
  GROSSEGANZZAHL BIGINT,
  GLEITKOMMAZAHL DECIMAL(17, 5)
)
```

But in Oracle I do get:

```
CREATE TABLE BSP_TABELLE
(
  NAME           VARCHAR2(255),
  DATUM          TIMESTAMP(6),
  RICHTIGFALSCH  NUMBER(1),
  BLUB           BLOB,
  CLUB           CLOB,
  GANZZAHL       NUMBER,
  GROSSEGANZZAHL NUMBER,
  GLEITKOMMAZAHL NUMBER(17, 5)
)
```

And I expected:

```
CREATE TABLE BSP_TABELLE
(
  NAME           VARCHAR2(255),
  DATUM          TIMESTAMP(6),
  RICHTIGFALSCH  NUMBER(1),
  BLUB           BLOB,
  CLUB           CLOB,
  GANZZAHL       NUMBER(10),
  GROSSEGANZZAHL NUMBER(19,0),
  GLEITKOMMAZAHL NUMBER(17, 5)
)
```

How can I achieve it, that the DataType for Oracle will fit, without modifying the datatypes in H2?

I am currently loading the changelog from the java implementation at runtime like:

```
Connection connection = openDatabaseConnection();
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
String[] validatedLiquibaseChangelogs = validateLiquibaseChangelogs();
for (String validatedChangelog : validatedLiquibaseChangelogs) {
    Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(validatedChangelog, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
    //Updaten der Datenbank
    liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
}
```

Comment: You can write different sets of `changeSets` for different databases. Sometimes, there's no way around it.

Comment: Searching the whole day I found, the following but had not time to try it: https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/1998878/SqlGenerator